# Send notification to all devices

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I followed the instruction in AndroidHive and i successed. But it only able me to send notification to particular user. I want to send to all users at a time. I tried to add a "loop" but it didnt work. Please help me.
-update-
Here is the index.php

```
        function sendPushNotification(id){
            var data = $('form#'+id).serialize();
            $('form#'+id).unbind('submit');                
            $.ajax({
                url: "send_message.php",
                type: 'GET',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                      $('.txt_message').val("");
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include_once 'db_functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $users = $db->getAllUsers();
    if ($users != false)
        $no_of_users = mysql_num_rows($users);
    else
        $no_of_users = 0;
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Đã có <?php echo $no_of_users; ?> người đăng ký nhận thông báo</h1>
        <hr/>
        <ul class="devices">
            <?php
            if ($no_of_users > 0) {
                ?>
                <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <form id="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>" name="" method="post" onsubmit="return sendPushNotification('<?php echo $row["id"] ?>')">
                            <label>Tên: </label> <span><?php echo $row["name"] ?></span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <label>Lớp / Tổ:</label> <span><?php echo $row["email"] ?></span>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="send_container">                                
                                <textarea rows="3" name="message" cols="25" class="txt_message" placeholder="Nhập thông báo"></textarea>
                                <input type="hidden" name="regId" value="<?php echo $row["gcm_regid"] ?>"/>
                                <input type="submit" class="send_btn" value="Gửi đi" onclick=""/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                <?php }
            } else { ?> 
                <li>
                    :)))
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

and send.php

```
if (isset($_GET["regId"]) && isset($_GET["message"])) {
$regId = $_GET["regId"];
$message = $_GET["message"];

include_once './GCM.php';

$gcm = new GCM();

$registatoin_ids = array($regId);
$message = array("price" => $message);

$result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

echo $result;
```

Comment: post code or the link of your tutorial.

Comment: show us your code please.. or that link to AndroidHive

Comment: just think if u able so send push to particular user so u can also send push to all user just do when u write code in php to single user to call loop

Comment: @bjiang [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the array of registration id

Here what if seen in the code

$registatoin_ids = array($gcm_regid1,$gcm_regid2);

Comment: it need "serialize". i think so

Comment: help me please. it need "serialize" but i dont know how to do